# How to get all contact list Mailjet in API?

Tags: mailjet

How can i to get all informations about Mailjet contact list ? ( list names, liste id ..ect ).

There have all contacts :

`$mj = new Mailjet( $apiKey, $secretKey );
 $result = $mj->contact();`

Now I want get the list contact.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the API sample provided, it seems that you are using the deprecated PHP wrapper of Mailjet. When using it, you can find the relation between a contact and contact list with the resource `listrecipient`. You can find similar sample here - >
https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php-simple#a-function-to-get-unsubscribed-contacts-from-a-list-with-id-listid

Details in the API reference -> https://dev.mailjet.com/email-api/v3/listrecipient/

As this wrapper is not supported anymore, I would recommend switching to the latest and fully maintained wrapper version -> https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php